# fontello иконки и событие click()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Входные данные:

```
<span class="button-search"></span>

$('.button-search').click(function() {
  // что то
})
```

При добавлении иконки в span

```
<span class="button-search"><i class="icon-search"></i></span>
```

Перестает работать событие click()

Answer (score 2):

Буквально из [соседнего ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/651555/191482):

> Потому что навешивание события происходит только на существующие на момент вызова элементы.
>   Можно навесить один-единственный обработчик на document, с селектором.

[jQuery.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).on('click', ".button-search", function() {
    // ...
});
```

Или не на весь документ, а на ближайшего родителя, который не подвержен динамическим изменениям.

```js
$('.test').on('click', ".button-search", function() {
 // ...
});
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <span class="button-search">
  <i class="icon-search"></i>
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: иконка изначально добавлена , статично

Comment: @MoJlo4HuK значит что-то делаете еще, что в вопросе не указали (например какие-то подгрузки данных или изменения контента). ваша проблема в таком случае просто не воспроизводится